# Right Methode for ML Modell

Tags: machine-learning, regression, artificial-intelligence, classification

I m making my first steps in AI and ML.
I choose myself a project, I want to fix with ML, but I m unsure which methode to use.

Business Case: A Customer can put offers and set a date he wants to receive his products.
He is able to change the amount of products he buys at every time.
I have to deal with the costs of unbuyed products and missing profit, in case I produced less than he wanted.
I have plenty of data from past transactions contianing the original amount of products ordered and the amount I sent to the costumer.
My goal is to get a predicitve analytics model which is able to tell me after a costumer changed the number of products from an order, how probably this change is final.

I m really new to this topic and are not quite getting all the information for the different methodes. I know classification and regression are the big players and can be implemented in different ways. But is one of those approaches fitting for my problem?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with a classification based approach. Since you goal is to predict whether the order change is final or not. The probability of happening that change can be derived from the accuracy/F1 score of your model. Higher the values, higher successful predictions. In laymen's terms think this as classifying whether the order is final or not.

You have to go for a regression approach if you're trying to predict a value based on the order change. For example if you want to predict what is the cost for the next order change, then you have to use regression.

As I understood your use case matches with the first scenario.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice, I also thought of my problem that way and had classification in mind. I will leave the question open over the weekend, in case others have intresting ideas too. Afterwards I will mark your answere as correct.